# ¿Cómo transformar un archivo json en un archivo geojson?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, geojson

Quiero transformar un archivo json `ciudades.json` en un archivo geojson. Por ejemplo :

```
[
  {
    "Province": "AZILAL",
    "Commune": "AIT ABBAS",
    "Type_Commune": "Rural",
    "Nbre_Inscrits": 445,
    "Nbre_Votants": 132,
    "Nbre_Nuls": 12,
    "Nbre_Exprimees": 120,
    "Turnout": 0.2696629213483146,
    "PI": 1,
    "PJD": 47,
    "PAM": 55,
    "USFP": 0,
    "APFGD": 0,
    "PPS": 11,
    "RNI": 0,
    "MP": 0,
    "UC": 0,
    "FFD": 1,
    "MDS": 1,
    "AAR": 0,
    "P Néo-Démocrates": 1,
    "PEDD": 0,
    "PRD": 2,
    "Winner": "PAM",
    "Swing": 1,
    "longitude": -6.5763368,
    "latitude": 33.1926354
  },
  {
    "Province": "AZILAL",
    "Commune": "AIT ABBAS",
...
```

Sólo sé que para convertir mis datos a un GeoJSON `Feature` o `FeatureCollection`. Las geometrías `GeoJSON`, `Point`, `Polygon`, `MultiPolygon`, etc., no soportan *atributos* como ipAddress y score, en su caso. Cómo definir una característica que tiene una geometría y atributos?

Intente lo siguiente:

```
#! usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv
from os.path import exists
import simplejson as json 

in_file, out_file = "map_input_pol_analysis.json", "map_input_pol_stn_analysis.geojson"

data = json.load(open(in_file))

geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [d["longitude"], d["latitude"]],
            },
        "properties" : d,
     } for d in data]
}


output = open(out_file, 'w')
json.dump(geojson, output)

print(geojson)
```

Pero me devuelve :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-a9b360e66970> in <module>
      7 in_file, out_file = "map_input_pol_analysis.json", "map_input_pol_stn_analysis.geojson"
      8 
----> 9 data = json.load(open(in_file))
     10 
     11 geojson = {

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py in load(fp, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, use_decimal, namedtuple_as_object, tuple_as_array, **kw)
    455 
    456     """
--> 457     return loads(fp.read(),
    458         encoding=encoding, cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    459         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 2395751: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como indica el mensaje de error, este se gatilla por un problema de decodificación del archivo JSON al abrirse.

A priori no me es posible saber con certeza que codificación posee dicho archivo, sin embargo probablemente esté en UTF-8 o Latin-1, dado que está en español y, por esto, debe poseer caracteres especiales.

Intenta cambiar la linea que abre y carga el JSON por las siguientes alternativas.

**Alternativa 1: UTF-8**

```
data = json.load(open(in_file, encoding='utf-8'))
```

**Alternativa 2: Latin-1**

```
data = json.load(open(in_file, encoding='latin-1'))
```